# Reading text file and parsing data into binary tree [C]

Tags: c, struct, file-io, malloc, binary-tree

Let's say I have a following structure:

```
struct _Tree_
{
    char* title;
    char* text;
    struct _Tree_* left;
    struct _Tree_* right;
}
```

Now I'm reading a text file that looks like this:

```
Title\n
firstfile.txt\n
secondfile.txt\n
text
```

Firstfile will always go to the left, and secondfile will always go to the right. Something like binary tree. Basically I want to read bounch of .txt files and store them with this rule. That means if my program opens firstfile.txt, it will create node on the left, store in that node title and text from that file and go on. In the same time it will open secondfile.txt and do the same process. However, end is when file looks like this:

```
Title\n
-\n
-\n
Text
```

I need advise how to approach to this problem. I want to start program like:
./program input.txt and now what I have is that first argument I will parse it into the function that will split every line and first line will be saved into struct as title, second will call struct *Tree** left, third will call struct *Tree** right, rest is text and that should be stored in the text. I'm aware of using malloc to make right size for title and for text. Can someone give me the best way to this this, idea or anything. Do I need to create new node and set left and right to NULL. If so, how to do it best way? 
Many thanks to people that even read this!

Comment: write a function that takes filename as argument and call it recursively

Comment: What are your file_names? Also could you give example maybe of 8  files and how they should be inserted in tree(breadth firstly)?

Comment: What are your file_names? Also could you give example maybe of 8  files and how they should be inserted in tree(breadth firstly)?